# How can I translate the google-services.json in my Unity project so that my firebase integration works in an buidl?

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, gradle, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to use a FireBase realtime database in [my Oculus Quest app](https://github.com/Spatial-Cinematics/Handtracking-Physics/blob/physicsButtons/Assets/Scripts/QuestionnaireManager.cs), but it seems like google-services isn't initializing properly when I build.

Everything works perfectly in my Unity Editor, and I'm not getting any errors. When I build to quest and use ADB Logcat I get this error:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   at QuestionnaireManager.GiveAnswer (System.Int32 answer) [0x00035] in <7ee908d4e96e4aa6a0d12545247f5f0d>:0 
>   at UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall`1[T1].Invoke (T1 args0) [0x00010] in <7717a69884ed4b33971896d8ee45333e>:0 
>   at UnityEngine.Events.CachedInvokableCall`1[T].Invoke (System.Object[] args) [0x00001] in <7717a69884ed4b33971896d8ee45333e>:0 
>   at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () [0x00074] in <7717a69884ed4b33971896d8ee45333e>:0 
>   at PhysicsButton.OnCollisionExit (UnityEngine.Collision other) [0x0002c] in <7ee908d4e96e4aa6a0d12545247f5f0d>:0

[This blog post](https://medium.com/@samstern_58566/how-to-use-firebase-on-android-without-the-google-services-plugin-93ecc7dc6c4) leads me to think that the XML files aren't initializing properly, but I'm having trouble following the steps they listed since I'm using Unity and don't know much about android-native, gradle, or gradle commands.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any specific Firebase related logs in that code snippet, but Oculus Quest will be an interesting platform either way.

The first thing you *should* do when you integrate Firebase with a Unity project is call `CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync`. What this does is check to see if the user has an up to date version of [Google Play Services](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/9037938?hl=en) on Android. On iOS and on the Desktop this call does nothing.

Google Play Services is also only available (to my knowledge) as a licensed service, it's not part of the Android Open Source Project. So mainstream Android phones and tablets tend to have access to it, but devices that fork Android (such as the Fire TV) do not. The Oculus Quest, to my knowledge, is running a forked version of Android without Google Play Services. If this assumption is accurate, then `CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync` will never return `DependencyStatus.Available`.

Now your specific question is about Realtime Database, which actually does not require Google Play Services (a good rule of thumb is that if it's [open source](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/), it doesn't require Play Services. But this isn't necessarily a guarantee). But if you use Firebase Authentication, which you probably do to effectively use Realtime Database rules, then *that* will require Play Services and definitely not run as-is on Android. Although this may hold at a native library level, remember that `CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync` will fail if your device doesn't support Play Services. In this situation, I do not know if `FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance` can ever be non-`null`, and therefore I don't know if `Database.DefaultInstance` can ever be non-`null` (in fact, [this bug](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/223) doesn't seem to bode well).

At this point, what are your options then?

If you're only developing an app for yourself, maybe you can sideload Play Services. I generally would recommend against this, as you're pulling a core piece of functionality from a possibly disreputable source. If you do this, everything will probably work (test on a phone before you do this just in case).

You could purely use the REST APIs. I've seen [this plugin](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/simple-firebase-unity-for-realtime-database-58337) come up a bit, but you'll be missing out on some of the work the Firebase Games team does to really take advantage of Android's native capabilities (one side effect of which is the whole play store dependency after all).

You could expose your entire backend via [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions)s (or [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run) if you wanted to [stay in the C# world](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-write-a-c-backend-for-a-unity-game-using-firebase-and-googles-cloud-run-adebf79a57f?source=friends_link&sk=12c75f13f49d70d5d9d08666445fc103)). If you use normal (vs. Callable) functions, these are simple rest calls.

You could also use [Unity's JNI interop](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJNIHelper.html) to try to use the native Android SDK directly. This can be a little painful (JNI is never fun, even with helpers), but you could even use [this project](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/auth-without-play-services) to get around the auth issues!

Oh, and above all else, file a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report). Even though [the bug](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/223) is locked, it's useful to get more input about what is needed and why. So include which device you want to target, why, what you need Firebase to do, and any other information you feel comfortable sharing about your game.